# Python: Accidentally assigned repr an int value

Tags: python, repr

I don't exactly know how I whiffed this, but at some point I input

```
repr = 64
```

into the python console in spyder. When I now try to run repr(b64) this happens:

```
repr(b64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-23-8c64b01419a6>", line 1, in <module>
    repr(b64)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

can I fix this without restarting spyder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete your variable:

```
del repr
```

This will clear the binding you created, unhiding the builtin. (It will not remove the builtin `repr`.) This gets you back to a slightly cleaner state than `repr = builtins.repr` would, though it usually won't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Use `builtins.repr`:

```
>>> repr = 42
>>> repr(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> from builtins import repr
>>> repr(42)
'42'
```

(or use `del` as suggested by user2357112).